# Nuxt 3,. Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

[cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPG1P.jpg)

const { status } = useAuth() as any

// if(status.value == 'authenticated' && ((data.value?.user?.contact == null || data.value?.user.contact == '') && to.path != '/profile/need-info')){

if (status.value == 'authenticated') {

```
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/profile/getUserOnly')

if (

  (data.value?.contact == null || data.value.contact == '') &&

  to.path != '/profile/need-info'

) {

  return navigateTo('/profile/need-info')

}
```

}

// if(status.value == 'authenticated' )

})`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.